# The difference between returning an object by value and by reference,object construction

Tags: c++, return-value, return-type

What does the function's return type really mean? What happens when we return an object? And what is the difference between return-by-value and return-by-reference?

```
class A{
   ...
};
A f1(){
    A *temp = new A;
    return *temp;
}
const A& f2(){
    A *temp = new A;
    return *temp;
}

int main(){
    A object1 = f1();
    A object2 = f2();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried this example code on VS2010 using step by step debugging (F10).
What is surprising,the copy constructor was called only 2 times. Once,from f1 function,and once from the main function. Why was the copy constructor called from f1 and how was object1 constructed?
I know that this is a very bad code,leaking resources,but I tried to concentrate our attention on the problem.

Comment: Search for RVO and copy-elision.

Comment: "... tried this example code on VS2010 ...". May I advice you to get a modern compiler that can use modern C++? With C++17 you'd get guaranteed copy-elision in many cases (which is relevant to your question). But even if you only get to C++14 you'll still be in a much happier place than with that old crud.

Comment: please one question per question. The thing about number of copy constructor calls can be answered but the rest is too broad imho.

Comment: I would be thankful for any helpful answer

Comment: Ron By the way,I was reading Scott Meyers Effective c++,and this question aroused after reading  item 20. And I had seen that list before. Thank you,anyways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot "return a reference". The phrase is a colloquialism that obscures details that matter if you actually care about the details.

A function call expression (e.g. `f(a, b, c)`) is an expression, and when evaluated it produces a *value*. A value is never a reference. All that matters about a value, apart from its type, is its *value category*, i.e. whether it is an lvalue, an xvalue or a prvalue.

There is a common way in C++ to encode a value category in the type system, which is used for function return types, casts, and for `decltype`. It goes like this. Assume that `U` is an object type.

- with `U f()`, `f()` is a prvalue, `decltype(f())` is `U`
- with `U& f()`, `f()` is an lvalue, `decltype(f())` is `U&`
- with `U&& f()`, `f()` is an xvalue, `decltype(f())` is `U&&`

What's important here is that `f` *always* "returns a `U`", but what matters is *which* value is returned.

Moreover, given a glvalue `x` of type `U`,

- `static_cast<U>(x)` is a prvalue (a "copy" or a "load"),
- `static_cast<U&>(x)` is an lvalue, and
- `static_cast<U&&>(x)` is an xvalue (this is what `std::move` does).

So, in summary, the following two statements are correct:

- "The return type of `f` is `U&`."
- "The function `f` returns an lvalue."

Colloquially, people will talk of "returning a reference", but what they really mean is "returning a glvalue" (because the two reference return types are used for the two kinds of glvalue). The distinction between glvalue and prvalue is the one we usually care most about, because a glvalue is an existing location, whereas a prvalue is a guarnanteed-unique new copy.

Comment: "...and when evaluated it produces a value." This needs clarification. It produces a value *where*? Inside the function definitioin, surely *something* is produced or calculated. But the OP possibly wants to know how this evaluated value within the function relates to what is returned in the calling program.

Comment: Thank you,I didn't know that. But what about the copy constructor called from f1? What object got copy constructed then? And how was object1 constructed?

Comment: @Grig: The return value of `f1` is constructed by copy from the expression `*temp` in the function body. The variable `object1` is notionally initialized from a copy of the return value. Both those copies are typically elided, so that you end up with a single copy that initializes `object1` from `*temp` directly. The effect is the same in `f2`, but the value of `f2()` *is* the actual object at `*temp`. There's still only one final copy, but only because you chose `object2` to be an object, not a reference. (I.e. your code obscures some of the interesting details.)

Comment: @Tryer: In the same way that `1 + 1` produces a value.

Comment: Also, for the sake of making your answer more precise, I suggest `glvalue` be introduced or defined prior to its usage. Otherwise, very enlightening answer, thanks!

Comment: @Kerrek SB so the copy constructor (for object1)was called 1 time,instead of 2,just because of the compiler optimization?

Comment: @Kerrek SB one more thing,how could I prevent memory leaks in this example? The destructor of object1 will be called by the end of the main function,but what about *temp?

Comment: @Grig: I mean, you prevent memory leaks by not writing any. The code in `f1` is completely absurd, to the point where it's completely unclear what real code it represents. The best I can guess is that you want something like `A f1() { return A(); }`. Just don't say `new` (ever).

Comment: @Kerrek SB is there a difference between return A(); and what I have wrote?

Comment: @Kerrek SB when you write return A(),the object you are creating to return is local and is created on the stack,isn't it?

Comment: @Grig: No, not really. The storage temporary objects (which is another name for "prvalues") is a bit murky. It's notionally "automatic", but due to all sorts of optimizations it's most likely never stored anywhere other than its very final destination.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Thank you for your answers very much.I have tried the simpliest example possible,the one you wrote in one of your previous comments. A f() { return A(); } and A object = f(); in main function. And the result is really shocking. Only one call to the constructor! Is it just the RVO?

Comment: @Grig: Pretty much, yes. You can try `-fno-elide-constructors` to inhibit RVO.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean call-by-ref and call-by-val??

> And what is the difference between return-by-value
>   and return-by-reference?

I will try to explain it for you in my following examples:

```
#include "iostream"


int calc1() { // call by value
    int c = 1 + 1;
    return c; // In this case you need to return the value
}

void calc2(int *c) { // Call by ref (with pointer)
    *c = 1 + 1;
} // In this case, you are working with pointers, thus you don't need to return the value


int main() {

    int c;

    // call by value
    c = calc1();
    printf("%i\n",c);

    c = 0;

    // call by ref
    calc2(&c); // you need  to pass the address of the variable
    printf("%i\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

> What does the function's return type really mean?

```
#include "iostream"


int calc1() { // return type is integer
    int i = 1 + 1;
    return i; // In this case you return an integer
}

double calc2 (){ // return type is double
    double c = 1.5 + 1.5;
    return c; // In this case you return an double
}


int main() {

    int i;
    double d;

    // call by value
    i = calc1(); // here you will get an integer back
    printf("%i\n",i);

    d = calc2(); // Here you will get an double back
    printf("%f\n",d);

    return 0;
}
```

You need to specify the return type for an function like the type of an variable. You will need this, to specify the type of the return value.
In my example above I'm assigning the return value of `calc2()` to `double d` as an double. If you are assigning the return value of `calc1()` to `double d`, you will get an error from the compiler.

Comment: Pointers are not references. If you want to call by reference, then by all means, use a *reference*.